# Ask if you have 500, 200, 100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 2 y 1 € in a for-in. Then, print the total

Tags: python

The error says:

```
(Line 7)'TypeError: raw_input() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 4 were given'
```

I'm starting, if someone could help me.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

l_b_p = (500, 200, 100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1)
suma = 0
    
for x in range(0,7):  
    suma = (l_b_p[x] * input('¿Cuántos billetes tiene de', l_b_p[x],'€?\n')) + suma
    
for x in range(7,9):
    print('¿Cuántas monedas tiene de', l_b_p[x],'€?\n')
    suma = suma + input()
```

Comment: There's no ``raw_input`` anywhere in that code; the Python *2* ``raw_input`` would only take 1 argument at most. On line 7, ``input`` is passed *3* arguments but only takes *1*, not 1 to 2, positional argument. Can you please [edit] the question to provide a [mre] and the full traceback?

Answer (score 1):

You are thinking that `input` works like `print` and automatically concatenates its parameters.  It doesn't.  It accepts only one string.

```
for x in range(0,7):  
    suma = (l_b_p[x] * input('¿Cuántos billetes tiene de'+str(l_b_p[x])+'€?\n')) + suma
```

Next, are you running Python 2 or Python 3?  The fact that you mentioned `raw_input` makes me think you're using Python 2.  In that case, `input` will evaluate your input and return an integer.  If you are on Python 3, `input` returns a string, and you must convert it:

```
for x in range(0,7):  
    suma = (l_b_p[x] * int(input('¿Cuántos billetes tiene de'+str(l_b_p[x])+'€?\n'))) + suma
```

The same thing would apply to your second loop:

```
    suma += int(input())
```

Comment: * Spyder version: 5.2.1 None
* Python version: 3.7.9 64-bit
* Qt version: 5.12.10
* PyQt5 version: 5.12.3
* Operating System: Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved like this (Thanks to [Tim Roberts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1883316/tim-roberts)):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

l_b = (500, 200, 100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1)
s = 0
    
for x in range(0,7):
    a = input('¿Cuántos billetes tiene de '+ str(l_b[x]) + '€? \n')
    s = int(a) * int(l_b[x]) + s
    
for x in range(7,9):
    a = input('¿Cuántas monedas tiene de '+ str(l_b[x]) + '€? \n')
    s = int(a) * int(l_b[x]) + s
    
print('El resultado total de la suma del dinero son '+ str(s)+'€ \n')
```